# UISearchBar functionality through UITextField

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I want to make a custom UISearchBar, but that is not possible through official APIs. So I want to implement the functionality of UISearchBar through UITextField with autosuggest from a server.

Code will be helpful but any direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?
I have the same issue. Could you please post any class you may have came up with?
Thank you.